# Nemo can't open trash

Tags: gnome, 16.04, trash, nemo

I initially installed Ubuntu 16.04 with gnome shell and everything that the flavor comes from. After a while nautilus was being a resource hog so I switched to Nemo since I didn't like it anyways.

But now, I cannot open my trash. Trying to do so gives this error:

```
Error: Failed to execute child process "/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash" (No such file or directory)
Please select another viewer and try again.
```

`~/.local/share/Trash` works perfectly fine however. This is definitely and issue with nemo somewhere.

The solution I thought of but couldn't apply is the change the directory for the trash folder to directly go to `~/.local/share/Trash/files` instead of running useless stuff. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: `~/.local/share/Trash/files` and `trash:///` are not the same thing. It wouldn't help to change the directory for the trash folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I started nemo from the command line (first killing it with `nemo -q`) and tried to open "trash", I got the following message:

```
Nemo-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 
  »net usershare« gab den Fehler 255 zurück: info_fn: 
  file /var/lib/samba/usershares/comics is not a well formed usershare file.
info_fn: Error was Path is not a directory.
```

I had created a share which I deleted later without un-sharing the folder.
Solution: looked in the given file "comics" for the original path, created the folder again, shared/unshared and deleted it. => "trash" is working again :-)